# view node reference

Tags: views, nodes

I have a content types **Person** and **Projects**
In Project I have Node reference fields of Person.
when i am adding a new project and select person who worked on that project using node reference field.

I like to create a view that contains the person who worked on a project. I want to display that view as a block beneath that project. For view the people who worked on that project.

I tried a lot of things (10 hours) to create the view. But not get proper result.
Now i have a view that shows all persons, also the persons that didn't work on that project. When i add a contextual filter or/and a relationship the view is empty.

Comment: Why do you want to use views? You can choose how to print your references in a node view of projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to create a view for this,

1. Create a new View Block of **project** content type.
2. Add your node reference field under fields and select rendered entity or label as you would want it to display.
3. Add a contextual filter **Content:Nid** and provide default value - Raw value from url. Select your proper path component and check path alias (if you are using path alias).
4. Go to structure -> blocks and move your block to your region and set the Content type - **projects** under visibility settings.